# bootstrap-select-country displaying only 1 country

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to display countries basically CA and USA in the dropdown but it only shows 1, I tried different options from the page in the select but doesn't work, always displaying only 1 country and that is without a flag, I need to display it with the flag, I don't understand what I am missing as I have included all the dependencies.

Here is the page for the code:

> ```
> https://babaraliseehar.com/select/myindex3.html
> ```

```
<select class="selectpicker countrypicker" data-flag="true" ></select>
```

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself, rather than simply providing a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try those options to s multiple choice:

```
<select class="selectpicker countrypicker" 
data-flag="true" data-live-search="true" multiple></select>
```